# Why does my page actualize on the anchor?

Tags: html, anchor, page-refresh

When i clicked on this button that i created [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsHvS.png) it makes me go there [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RUyz.png) and that is what i want. But it's what comes after that that is the unwanted result.

When i actualized the page, it will makes me go there again, i can understand why since the url will not change there since it was " [...]index.html#nom " and it will become the same after actualizing  the page after i clicked on the button. But when i do something else, like clicking on the button " Accueil " the url will be this [index.html] but it will not make me go at the start of the page but there [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE2Qn.png) when i want to be there [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbsX2.png).

So my question is this. Why when i actualize my page without clicking the button or clicking " Accueil"  or clicking "Accueil" or the other "Accueil" in the three others pages [à propos ; Tarifs ; Portfolio] that is supposed to make me go at the start of the page " [...]index.html " it will make me go to " Voir mon portfolio " (seen in image 3).

I tried to understand why it doesn't work. But if i understand correctly.

If i use a <a href"#nom"> TEST . When a id="nom" was created before. When i clicked on the " TEST " it will makes me go at the same page, but at the id where it was located in the page. So in my case it works. But when i clicked on other things that's supposed to make me go at the start of the " Accueil" page. it just makes me go at another location.

I tried to use another ID with another anchor just to make the " Accueil  " of the page accueil; à propos ; tarifs ; portfolio makes me go to the same anchor located at the start of the page so it  will works out. But again, the url will change and it will be this " [...]index.html#haut ". So there go another problem. If i just actualize my page without the #haut it will make go at the location of image4 and if have already clicked on the button ( seen in image 1) then i need to click on the " Accueil" at the top... to go at the top of the page. So it kinds of lost his meaning.

While doing what i'm doing will makes it work. It doesn't work on some cases :

- 1 : If i'm going to the index page the first time, the url will be " [...] index.html " so it will makes me go at the location of image4.
- 2 : If i'm clicking on the button seen in image1, the url will change to " [...] index.html#nom ", and if i actualize the page it will makes me go there again. So if i want to go at the start of my page i need to go at the start by scrolling and clicking on Accueil, but it's not that great (since i don't need to click on accueil since i'm already at the start of the page).

I tried looking on the internet, but it only gave me explanation of the anchor and id and it doesn't seem like i did something wrong here so i don't really know.

```
<body>
    <header>
         <nav>
             <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo Robbie Lens"  id="haut">
             <div>
                 <a href="index.html#haut">Accueil</a>
                 <a href="À propos - Robbie Lens Photographie.html">À propos</a>
                 <a href="tarif.html">Tarif</a>
                 <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
              </div>
         </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="accueil-introduction">
            <div>
                <h1>Robbie Lens Photographie</h1>
                <p>
                    Où <em>professionalisme</em> s’allie avec <em>passion</em>. Depuis
                    plus de 5 ans maintenant, j’exerce mon métier avec la passion
                    qui m’anime : capturer l’essence de chaque instant.
                 </p>
                <a href="index.html#nom" class="cta">UN PROJET ? ÉCRIVEZ-MOI</a>
            </div>
            <img src="robbie-lens.png" alt="Portrait avec effet de la photographe Robbie Lens" >
        </section>
        <section class="accueil-photos">
            <h2>Mon dernier projet</h2>
            <div>
                <img src="element-1.png" alt="Twelve apostles - Australie" >
                <img src="element-2.png" alt="Wai-O-Tapu - Nouvelle-Zélande" >
                <img src="element-3.png" alt="Parc National d’Abel Tasman - Nouvelle-Zélande" >
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="element-4.png" alt="Lac Rotorua - Nouvelle-Zélande" >
                <img src="element-5.png" alt="Milford Sound - Nouvelle-Zélande" >
                <img src="element-6.png" alt="Lac Wanaka - Nouvelle-Zélande" >
            </div>
        <div>
            <a href="portfolio.html" class="cta">VOIR MON PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h2 class="tortue" >Parlons de votre projet</h2>
            <form method="get" action="#">
                <div class="form-nom-email">
                    <div class="form-column">
                    <label for="nom">nom</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" required autofocus>
                    <label for="email">e-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-column">
                    <label for="message">Votre message</label><br>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea               required>
                    <input type="submit" value="ENVOYER" class="cta">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo Robbie Lens" >
        <div>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/" class="lien-icone">
                <img src="twitter.png" alt="Logo Twitter" >
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="lien-icone">
                <img src="instagram.png" alt="Logo Instagram" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Thanks for your answer and if the question was already made and answered i'm sorry.

Have a nice day.

Comment: "actualize" is "refresh", right?

Comment: Could you explain what you expect to happen vs. what actually happens in way less text? I'm not sure i understand it all. Also, are you using some sort of single-page application framework / library ? or is this a regular multi page app ?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yes, "actualiser" is French for "refresh", and mis-translated here.

Comment: Sorry, i mistook refresh and actualize. What i expect to happen is : If i clicked on " Accueil " it makes me go to the first page at the top. What actually happens is when i clicked on the " Accueil " it makes me go at the place seen in image 3.  It's a regular multi page app.